# How to eliminate all terms of a variable with square root in an equation?

Tags: code-review

I did the following thing: take an equation with square root terms, by moving terms and squaring two sides, finally ending up with a polynomial of the specific variable.

My algorithm is like this: first expand the expression, then get all the terms into a list by deleting the `Plus` head, and `Map` a similar function inside to delete the `Times` head. Then I will get the list I can pick the "power of 0.5" terms out. By iterating :moving the other terms to the other side and square and take back until all the square roots are eliminated.Then call the function it self to deal with nest square roots.

```
ExpandEquationWithSqrt[expr_, var_] := 
 Module[{process, sqrts, iter, expr2}, expr2 = Expand[expr]; 
  process = {ReleaseHold[Delete[Hold[Evaluate@expr2], {1, 0}]]}; 
   sqrts = DeleteDuplicates@Select[Flatten@(If[ToString[#[[0]]] == 
       "Times", {ReleaseHold[Delete[Hold[Evaluate@#], {1, 0}]]}, #] & /@ 
    process), #[[0]] == Power && #[[2]] == 1/2 &]; 
 sqrts = Select[sqrts, MemberQ[DeleteDuplicates@Cases[#, _Symbol, Infinity], var] &];
  iter[1] = expr2; 
  If[Length[sqrts] >= 1, 
   Do[iter[i] = Collect[iter[i], sqrts[[i]]]; 
iter[i + 1] = (iter[i] - PolynomialMod[iter[i], sqrts[[i]]])^2 -
  (PolynomialMod[iter[i], sqrts[[i]]])^2, {i, Length[sqrts]}]; 
   ExpandEquationWithSqrt[iter[Length[sqrts] + 1], var], 
   Collect[Expand@expr2, var]]]
```

Here are some examples:

```
ExpandEquationWithSqrt[Sqrt[(x + a)] - (a + b) Sqrt[x + a], x]
(*a - 2 a^2 + a^3 - 2 a b + 2 a^2 b + a b^2 + (1 - 2 a + a^2 - 2 b + 2 a b + b^2) x*)
ExpandEquationWithSqrt[(1 - a - b) Sqrt[(x + Sqrt[x + a])], x]
(*a - 4 a^2 + 6 a^3 - 4 a^4 + a^5 - 4 a b + 12 a^2 b - 12 a^3 b + ...
4 a b^3 - b^4) x^2*)
```

It worked. But many parts of my code, especially the part I extract square roots are really weird, and may be unreliable. Any suggestions to optimise?

Comment: See if `GroebnerBasis[expr,var][[1]]` gives you something likeable.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau `GroebnerBasis` gives `(-1 + a + b)(a + x)`, but OP's code gives `(-1 + a + b)^2 (a + x)`.

Comment: Let me understand: you're trying to get a polynomial that has the same roots as the original equation?  In that case Daniel's answer works, and does one better by removing the double roots that yours produces.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I noticed that you [really like](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=GroebnerBasis+user%3A51) `GroebnerBasis`, now I see why!

Comment: @2012rcampion When your only tool is a Swiss army knife, every problem starts to look like an invasion of Habsburgs. Or something to that effect.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank you, I didn't know about that function before.

Comment: @happyfish How do you employ GroebnerBasis into you code...I have a equation (polynomial) with squareroots and I like to have square root eliminated as well.